# Queries to check if strings are equivalent

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, hashmap

Given 2 strings A and B of same length N are considered equivalent if following conditions are true for all `1 <= i, j <= N`:

```
(Ai != Aj) <=> (Bi != Bj)
(Ai = Aj) <=> (Bi = Bj)
```

where `S[i]` denotes the ith (1-based indexing) character of string S.

**NOTE : If strings A and B are equivalent, strings B and C are equivalent, then strings A and C are also equivalent.**

Given 2 strings A and B of the same length N. We need to answer Q queries. Each query consists of 3 integers i, j, k, and for given query we need to check whether strings `A[ i, i + k - 1]` and `B[ j, j + k - 1]` are equivalent or not.

**Example** : Let `A = "abbcd"` and `B = "cccad"` and we have 2 Queries :

> Query 1 : i=1 , j=1 and k=2 then answer is NO
>
> Query 2 : i=3 , j=3 and k=3 then answer is YES

What can be best possible way to answer this query in most efficient way ? I think there can be some pre-processing done at start by storing locations of all 26 English alphabets and then doing binary search type of approach. But it fail in some cases. So how to solve this problem for given strings and Q queries.

Comment: The best approach I can think of right now is: I will use Java as the implementation language: you can go ahead with using ArrayList and store each character of the string as an element in the ArrayList, and then based upon your requirements/ checks, simply access the required portions of the ArrayList using ArrayList.get(index) call.

Comment: @AshwinTumma And whats its complexity ?

Comment: @Mrinal is copying this question has been just asked as a competition question on Hackerearth. Cmon grow up

Comment: Active competition? Damn, wasted minutes sketching a (_the_:-) solution. Thought about noting this would make a decent assignment, and a dubious interview question - why didn't I think of competitions? Think about distances between same characters.

Comment: I don't think this is [HackerEarth _equivalent-strings-1_](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/equivalent-strings-1/), or that an answer to this question is much help with that problem.

Answer (score 2):

Idea: create a normalization function that lets us check the equivalence relation for a pair of strings by just doing a regular string match on the "normalized" strings.

The equivalence relation seems to basically check whether a [simple substitution cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher#Simple_substitution) matching the strings exists. So for the normalization step, we use one that replaces letters based on their first occurrence  (code in Java):

```
String normalize(String s) {
  char available = 'A';
  Map<Character, Character> seen = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length; s++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    Character replacement = seen.get(c);
    if (replacement == null) {
      replacement = available++;
      seen.put(c, replacement);
    }
    result.append(replacement);
  }
  return result.toString();
}
```

Use the normalization in the query:

```
boolean query(String a, String b, int i, int j, int k) {
  return normalize(a.substring(i - 1, i + k)).equals(
         normalize(b.substring(j - 1, j + k)));
}
```

Now we can integrate this into a single specialized function, avoiding all the copying:

```
boolean query(String a, String b, int i, int j, int k) {
  Map<Character, Character> seenA = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
  Map<Character, Character> seenB = new HashMap<Character, Character>();
  char available = 'A';
  for (int p = 0; p < k; p++) {
    char ca = a.charAt(i + p - 1);
    char cb = b.charAt(j + p - 1);
    Character replacementA = seenA.get(ca);
    Character replacementB = seenB.get(cb);
    if (replacementA == null ? replacementB != null :
        !replacementA.equals(replacementB)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (replacementA == null) {
      seenA.put(ca, available);
      seenB.put(cb, available);
      available++;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

let A, B, your 2 strings of length N.

let A2,B2, 2 matrices N x N, where A2(i,j) = A[i]==A[j].

So :

```
for 1 <= i,j <= N
{
  A2(i,j) = A[i] == A[j]
  B2(i,j) = B[i] == B[j]
}
```

Then comparing 2 matrix is pretty long. But the matrices contains only `{1,0}`. So instead of considering a `A2` matrix, you can use a vector of boolean (in c++ or list in java/c#).

So let Va,Yb, two boolean vector (for A & B resp.) :

```
for 1 <= i,j <= N
{
  Va(i * N + j) = A[i] == A[j]
  Vb(i * N + j) = B[i] == B[j]
}
```

Then, your property is equivalent to Va == Vb.

In terms of speed you can improve the implementation reducing the memory usage. A 64bits integer car store 64 values.

So, again :

So let V64_a,Y64_b, two vector of 64bits unsigned int (for A & B resp.) of length (N*N/64)+1:
Init them with 0.

```
for(i=1 ; i< N ; i++)
{
  // special case, comparing ith char with ith char : always true
  Va[i*i/64] = Va[i*i/64] | (1 << i%64)
  Vb[i*i/64] = Vb[i*i/64] | (1 << i%64)

  for( j=i+1 ; j < N ; ++j)
  {
    Va[i*i/64] = Va[i*i/64] | ((A[i] == A[j] ? 1 : 0 ) << i%64)
    Vb[i*i/64] = Vb[i*i/64] | ((B[i] == B[j] ? 1 : 0 ) << i%64)
  }
}
```

Then, A == B <=> Va == Vb.

Comment: I didnt get you answer in any way. Please explain a bit more with some example

Comment: your problem is to compare some properties of equivalence inside a given string and try to check if this property is valid also for other string. In that case your global property of equivalence is the same correct ? Your are not looking to compare some substring right ?

Comment: Let the property A(s,i,j)  = the i_th char is equals to the j_th char for string s; So I compute a matrix where at row i, col j, you get a 1 is the ith char and jth char are the same. Then, transform this matrix in an integer so the comparison between two strings A & B are just integer comparison.

Comment: Please note that string length can be upto 100000

Comment: How are you answering the queries ? Can you explain the example quoted in post ?

Comment: The queries are just a sub-problem of the one my proposal solves. i and j are always the same as shown in your 2 examples ?

Comment: No its not necessary that i and j are always same

Comment: @norisknofun - well it is more memory efficient, but if you create it as boolean array, it is more readable and faster (not that much suboperation needed). Still nice solutioun though :).

Comment: @norisknofun So can you explain how to answer a query of type i j and k

Comment: Houston ? We have a problem ! My solution S(A,B) solves the problem only if you consider Q(i,j,k, X, Y) => S(A, B), Q is your Query, X, Y, your 2 strings, A=X[i, i+k-1] and B=Y[j, j+k-1] the two adhoc substrings extracted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is fully working Java example with complexity O(k) for every query without any preprocessing.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JavaApplication14 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "abbcd";
        String b = "cccad";

        equivalency(a, b, 3, 3, 3);
        equivalency(a, b, 1, 1, 2);        
    }

    public static void equivalency(String a, String b, int i, int j, int k){
        List<Character> orderA = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Character> orderB = new ArrayList<>();

        Map<Character, List<Integer>> mapA = createMap(a, i, k, orderA);
        Map<Character, List<Integer>> mapB = createMap(b, i, k, orderB);

        if (orderA.size() != orderB.size()) {
            System.out.println("NO");
            return;
        }

        for (int l = 0; l < orderA.size(); l++) {
            List<Integer> valuesA = mapA.get(orderA.get(l));
            List<Integer> valuesB = mapB.get(orderB.get(l));

            if (valuesA.size() != valuesB.size()) {
                System.out.println("NO");
                return;
            }

            for (int m = 0; m < valuesA.size(); m++) {
                if (valuesA.get(m).equals(valuesB.get(m)) == false) {
                    System.out.println("NO");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("YES");        
    }

    public static Map<Character, List<Integer>> createMap(String input, int pos, int count, List<Character> characterOrder) {
        Map<Character, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
        input = input.substring(pos-1, pos+count-1);

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char ch = input.charAt(i);
            if (map.containsKey(ch) == false) {
                characterOrder.add(ch);
                map.put(ch, new ArrayList<>());
            }

            map.get(ch).add(pos);
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

output for this example is :

```
YES
NO
```

(if you find input which should have different output than this program actually has, let me know, I will fix it)

---

What does it actually do? When you look at first character in both strings you comparing, the position of same character (for each string) must appear in same position as the other string. If it does not, it is not equal. And it is same with any other character - second character has to have list of appearence position same in both string etc.

This code creates list of appearences for each character and keeps it in this structur : `Map<Character, List<Integer>>`, you also need to know which character was found first, which second etc. for comparing these positions, so for this I am using `List<Character>`.

AT the end of method I take first discovered character in String A, find it in map a return its arraylist of appearence. And I do the same for String B. Then I compare all values of string A and string B. If it fits, I continue on next character, if not, it is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

For each character position `pos` from 1 to `k`, the respective  characters `a` and `b` from `A` and `B` need to both occur for the first time *or* be paired as before. Using java Collections, one way to check this is to `put(a, b)` in a `Map m`: if the result does equal neither `null` nor `b`, the answer should be NO. If all equal `a`s were mapped to equal `b`s, it remains to be checked whether different `a`s were mapped to different `b`s, which should be true if the `values()` are unique

```
Collection<Character> values = m.values();
return new HashSet(values).size() == values.size() ? YES : NO;
```

(Alternatively, repeat the check reversing the roles of `A` and `B` or do these checks in parallel or …)
If the amount of queries justifies preprocessing, keep arrays `bdA` and `bdB` of "backward distances": how far back has the character at the current position last occurred before? (If not at all, use `N+1`.) For a query, for `pos` from `2` to `k`, if `bdA[i + pos] != bdB[j + pos]` and at least one is below `pos`, the answer should be NO. (If both are equal to or above `k`, both are first occurrences in range.)

Comment: If I understand your solution correctly, it would not work properly. For example for strings "abab" and "abba" - first occurences are same, the "second or more" occurences too, but it is not "equality" by author's definition.

Comment: `Map` approach: for position 1, (`'a', 'a'`) should be put in an empty `Map`. Putting (`'a', 'b'`) for position 2 should return `'a'`, which is neither `null` nor `'b'`, so the answer is NO. -*-O-*-
`int []`  approach: the arrays would be `{ 5, 5, 2, 2 }` and `{ 5, 5, 1 3 }`.